# Make counter only count letters, not whitespace

Tags: java, whitespace, removing-whitespace

Seems pretty simple but I am new to coding. I am trying to set up a counter to count each letter of a user's entered string, but I don't want to count white space.

I have seen a lot of people recommended using the replaceAll() function, but I have not yet learned about that and don't know how/where to define it. Wondering if there is another way, and if not, how to call/the syntax of the replaceAll(" ", ""), and where it is placed in the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Vowel_Counter
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int aCount= 0 , eCount= 0, iCount= 0;
        int total= 0, totalConsonant= 0, count = 0;
        char vowels= 0, i = 0;


        String userInput;

        System.out.println("Please enter a string of any lenth, or character combination");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    String userIntput = Vowel_Counter.replace(" ","");

        userInput = scan.nextLine(); 



        for (count = 0; count < userInput.length(); count++) 
        {


            vowels = userInput.charAt(count); 

            switch (vowels)
            { 
            case 'a':
                aCount++;
                break;
            case 'e':
                eCount++;
                break;
            case 'i':
                iCount++;
                break;

            }

        }
            System.out.println("There are " +aCount+ " a's in that string"); 
            System.out.println("There are " +eCount+ " e's in that string");
            System.out.println("There are " +iCount+ " i's in that string");

           total = userInput.length();


            System.out.println("The total lenth is " + total + " charactors");

        totalConsonant = total - aCount -eCount -iCount;

System.out.println("There are " + totalConsonant+ " non-vowels in that string");
}
```

}

If the string entered is "i love dogs", it should output 
"there are 0 a's"
"there are 1 e's"
"there are 1 i's"
"the total length is 9 characotrs"
"there are 5 non-vowels"

(the code does include counters for every vowel, but I've shortened it for the question)

Comment: What is your current output?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the easiest (most understandable) way is to check if the character is whitespace, and skip if so:

```
int charCount = 0;
for (count = 0; count < userInput.length(); count++) 
    {
        input = userInput.charAt(count); 

        if(input == ' ')
            continue;

        charCount++;

        switch (input)
        { 
        case 'a':
            aCount++;
            break;
        case 'e':
            eCount++;
            break;
        case 'i':
            iCount++;
            break;
        //(...other two cases)
        default:
            totalConsonant++;
        }
    }

System.out.println("There are " +aCount+ " a's in that string"); 
System.out.println("There are " +eCount+ " e's in that string");
System.out.println("There are " +iCount+ " i's in that string");
// ... other two cases


System.out.println("The total length is " + charCount + " characters");

System.out.println("There are " + totalConsonant + " non-vowels in that string");
```

I would probably also recommend using replaceAll(), but if you're asking for a different way, this should do it in a pretty straightforward way. The 'continue' keyword will skip the rest of the loop and proceed to the next iteration.

I also just made the default case adding a count to TotalConsonant, so you don't have to do the messy subtraction at the end.

Again, certainly not the most efficient, but it shows a pretty straightforward approach to this.

Using replaceAll():

```
userInput = scan.nextLine().replaceAll(" ", "");

for (count = 0; count < userInput.length(); count++) 
{
    vowels = userInput.charAt(count); 

    switch (vowels)
    { 
        case 'a':
            aCount++;
            break;
        case 'e':
            eCount++;
            break;
        case 'i':
            iCount++;
            break;
        // ...
        default:
            totalConsonant++;
    }
}

System.out.println("There are " +aCount+ " a's in that string"); 
System.out.println("There are " +eCount+ " e's in that string");
System.out.println("There are " +iCount+ " i's in that string");
// ... other two cases

System.out.println("The total length is " + userInput.length() + " characters");

System.out.println("There are " + totalConsonant + " non-vowels in that string");
```